# MongoDB: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $not needs a regex or a document

Tags: mongodb

**Some** of my documents contain a field named `status` with the value `404`.
I do not wish to return those files, so I use the `$not` operator:

```
query = {
    "venue_id": venue_id,
    "status": {
         "$not": 404
    } 
}
```

However I get an error:

```
OperationFailure: database error: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue
$not needs a regex or a document
```

Does this happen because **some** of the docs have that field? I do not wish to use regex for speed reasons. How can I make this query correctly and efficiently?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think I found it. It needed `$ne`.

```
query = {
    "venue_id": venue_id,
    "status": {
         "$ne": 404
    } 
}
```